# How can I use two model in a single view

Tags: qt

I want to use two data model in a single view.
A child of one model is the root of another data model.
Where one data model is ended(depth) another data model root start.

Comment: I think this is not possible. But you can create another model that would request data from two underlying models and align it in the desired way.

Comment: see 'Master Detail Example' in qtCreator

Comment: Thanks PavelStrakhov and CapelliC